# Undefined symbols error during compilation

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class Node declared in `node.h`. The methods are defined in `node.cc`. I have another class Tree declared in `tree.h`, with its methods defined in `tree.cc`.

The `insertPoint` method in tree creates a `Node* node` variable and calls the `insertNode` method with `node` as a parameter. The `insertNode` in turn invokes various methods of the Node class such as `addChild`, `setLevel`, `getMinDist` etc, for example: `node->getMinDist(...)`, `node->setLevel(...)`

Full source is here : https://github.com/apoorvreddy/covertree

```cpp
class Node {
private:
  Point *point;
  int level;
  std::vector<Node*> children;

public:
  Node(Point *p) {
    point = p;
  }

  Node(Point* p, int l) {
    point = p;
    level = l;
  }

  ~Node();

  Point* getPoint();
  std::vector<Node*> getChildren();
  int getLevel();
  void setLevel(int l);
  void addChild(Node *n);
  double getDistance(Node* node);
  double getMinDist(std::vector<Node*> nodeList);

};



class Tree {
private:
  float base;
  int maxLevel;
  int minLevel;
  Node* root;
  std::vector<Point> pointSet;
  bool insertNode(Node* node, std::vector<Node*> coverset_qi, int level);
public:
  Tree();
  void insertPoint(Point& point);
 };
```

However when I try to compile this code, I get the following error. What am I doing wrong !?

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "Node::getMinDist(std::__1::vector >)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  Tree::insertNode(Node*, std::__1::vector<Node*, std::__1::allocator<Node*> >, int) in tree.o
> ```
>
> "Node::getChildren()", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  Tree::insertNode(Node*, std::__1::vector<Node*, std::__1::allocator<Node*> >, int) in tree.o
> ```
>
> "Node::getDistance(Node*)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  Tree::insertNode(Node*, std::__1::vector<Node*, std::__1::allocator<Node*> >, int) in tree.o
> ```
>
> "Node::addChild(Node*)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  Tree::insertNode(Node*, std::__1::vector<Node*, std::__1::allocator<Node*> >, int) in tree.o
> ```
>
> "Node::getLevel()", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  Tree::insertNode(Node*, std::__1::vector<Node*,
> ```
>
> std::__1::allocator >, int) in tree.o
>
> "Node::getPoint()", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  Tree::insertNode(Node*, std::__1::vector<Node*, std::__1::allocator<Node*> >, int) in tree.o
> ```
>
> "Node::setLevel(int)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  Tree::insertNode(Node*, std::__1::vector<Node*, std::__1::allocator<Node*> >, int) in tree.o
> ```

Comment: Where is the definiton of these functions? How does your compiler command line look?

Comment: Hi, I've defined these functions in different files namely node.cc and tree.cc. For the sake of brevity, I have not pasted them here.

I'm compiling this using a Makefile.

This is the relevant part of the makefile.

`point.o: point.cc point.h`

  `$(CC) -c -o point.o point.cc $(CFLAGS)`

`node.o: node.cc node.h`

  `$(CC) -c -o node.o node.cc $(CFLAGS)`

`tree.o: tree.cc tree.h node.o point.o`

  `$(CC) -c -o tree.o tree.cc $(CFLAGS)`

Comment: More important is my second question.

Comment: Hi, this is the link to my source: https://github.com/apoorvreddy/covertree

Comment: there is no node.o in your linker list of objects $(CC) -g -v -o knn cli_main.cc utils.o point.o covertree.o $(CFLAGS)

Comment: Thank you !! I don't know how I missed it ! It compiles now :)